# linkage error upon starting webapplication on websphere 8.5.5

Tags: web-server, websphere

While I am trying to start the my web application on websphere 8.5.5 it failed with linkage error.

But it will work 100% correctly when I restart the websphere from services (if I do stopserver then startserver it will not work)

any idea guys why stop and start does not work as restart the websphere from services ?

I believe stop and start the server should have the same effect as the restart service !

Comment: Please post your logs or the exact error message.  Your description is far to vague to allow others to help you.

Comment: @tristan, yes I know its very general question, because I don't have the logs. but what I am looking for if someone know why stop/start server does not work like restart the service from windows services

Comment: Try to restart the service again to get the exact error message.